# Hotend Will NOT Heat Up with Bullseye

Tags: hotend, creality-cr-10, speed, cooling

So I just printed my Bullseye mod for my cr-10. But now I have a problem, when my hotend is trying to heat up it can't, because the cooling is to powerful. I know this because when I stop the fan with my finger it starts heating up. Is there any way I can make the fan slow down when printing (because it's not printing properly either) and total stop or go at a minuscule amout when heating up.

Help is Appreciated

Comment: Welcome to 3dPrinting.SE! In the slicer you can limit the amount of cooling fan ... even turn it off if you wanted to.

Comment: Make sure that the part-cooling fan is connected to a port that can be controlled by G-code. The port intended for the hot-end fan is often (but not always) hard-wired to the power supply.

Comment: What is a Bull's-eye mod?

Comment: @0scar https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2759439   Alec do you have it installed too high where it is blowing on the heater block instead of the nozzle? Also what slicer are you using?

Comment: Also, always use a silicone sock on your heater block.